# Queue jenkins job task in azure pipeline won't complete

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have set up an azure devops pipeline with a single task - to queue a jenkins build job. The jenkins job is a parameterised pipeline build. The job queues and runs as expected in Jenkins. I would expect the azure pipeline task to complete once the jenkins job is finished and to reflect the success status of the jenkins build, but what is currently happening is that the azure task never completes and simply runs to timeout.

I have selected both the;

"Capture console output and wait for completion"

and

"Capture pipeline output and wait for pipeline completion"

options in the configuration for the task, as far as I am aware that should do exactly as I expect.

I don't have the TFS jenkins plugin installed and would rather avoid doing so if it's not strictly necessary.

I can see that the teamBuildRequestCallback(teamBuildPostData) call from the task is generating a 404 response but I'm not sure why that's the case.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, worked for me after I changed the plugin version from 1 to 2